# PHP preg_match_all with Multiple Words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to test a string for all pattern matches of several words which are the beginning of words.  If not all patterns matched, I want to treat the query as False.  The beginning of word testing is working, but I get duplicate matches, which I find surprising as I would have thought, that once one match was found for a word, it would not test again for that word.  Perhaps I need to restrict the tests to one match somehow.

I imagined if I was testing for 3 words, then a successful test would return 3.

The return values are misleading as you can see from the example.  I am getting a positive value, which is greater than the number of words I am testing.  In the case of a non matching group, I am still getting a value higher than the number of words to be tested because of multiple matches of some words.

I guess I have not fully understood something or somehow I need to force an AND situation.

I have googled for answers, but none seem specific to my problem.

```
$image = 'After A!!BC DEF hello bugggy bad Sled bob bobert robob Triumph 2000 Roadster clearing bobby Sledmere ^ August 2014 ^ error';

$result = preg_match_all($query, $image, $matches);

$query = '#\b(bob|bug|sled)#i';  // ALL MATCH
Return Value 6 [ bob x 3, bug x 1, sled x 1]

$query = '#\b(bob|bug|led)#i'; // Two matches 'led' fails
Return Value 4 [ bob x 3, bug x 1, led x 0]
```

Comment: If I understand well you want to check if all words are present only one time?

Comment: No, I want to know that all words in the pattern match at least once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several lookaheads:

```
$text = 'After A!!BC DEF hello bugggy bad Sled bob bobert robob Triumph 2000 Roadster clearing bobby Sledmere ^ August 2014 ^ error';   
$pattern = '~^(?=.*\bbob)(?=.*\bbug)(?=.*\bsled)~i';   
if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) echo 'OK!';
```

Comment: That returns 0 on my test.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  I have got a return of 1 now, which maybe is what I want.  I will do further testing and get back.

Comment: Looks good.  I will mark it as answer tomorrow, if I can not fault it overnight.

Comment: I can not fault the answer, so will mark as correct - many thanks. **@CD001** - thanks for pointing out `preg_match_all` was the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$image = 'After A!!BC DEF hello bugggy bad Sled bob bobert robob Triumph 2000 Roadster clearing bobby Sledmere ^ August 2014 ^ error';

$query = '#\b(bob|bug|sled)(.*?) #i';  // ALL MATC

preg_match_all($query, $image, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: As I understand the question the string must contain "bob", "bug" and "sled" at the start of any word - **all** of them, or return false - this will evaluate as true if **any** of those terms are present at the start of any word; rather than requiring all of them somewhere.

Comment: An interesting result. 'bob' matched once and 'sled' matched once, but 'bug' did not match.  What does the addition of a blank character do ?

Comment: Sorry it is back to the original situation, giving a value of 6.  bobx3, sledx2, bugx1